# Application redirects to another application

Tags: php, facebook

I saw it in one app. I want that my app after publishing info on user wall redirects to  another facebook tab with application. How can I make it? Thanks for answer.

I saw it in this app: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Zmien-Kolor-Swojego-Fejsa/438226459533001?sk=app_190322544333196

Comment: I haven't tried anything

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with javascript and something like that :

```
window.top.location.href = "http://some-url.com";
```